# Regex pattern to find text either of two URLs

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
(?<=unit/)(.*)(?=/)
```

I use it to get a page name between `unit` and the guid.

```
www.page.com/module/unit/design/6e8c1d2b-34vc-4b5c-71af-8b0f93b01b60?sid=5fh6y172-31d9-4r6b-9a15-daed6c541162&culture=en-US
```

Now i am receiving an URL like this, with  `/load` before the sid.

```
www.page.com/module/unit/design/6e8c1d2b-34vc-4b5c-71af-8b0f93b01b60/load?sid=5fh6y172-31d9-4r6b-9a15-daed6c541162&culture=en-US
```

so i am getting this result from the regex

```
design/6e8c1d2b-34vc-4b5c-71af-8b0f93b01b60
```

How can i change the regex in order to get just `design`, moreover  how can i create a regex that find design either or both URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.*` use `[^/]*` to match any sequence of characters not including `/`. This will get everything until the next `/`.

```
(?<=unit/)[^/]*
```